# Error importando "Injectable" de Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Archivo ***color.service.ts***:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { GLOBAL } from '../services/global';

@Injectable()
export class ColorService {
    public url: string;
    constructor(private http:HttpClient){
        this.url = GLOBAL.url;
    }
    LoadData(data){
        const link = this.http.post( this.url+'colores/listar', data )
        .subscribe(
            resp=> {
              console.log(resp);
            },
            error => {
                console.log("Error", error);
            }
        );
        return link
    }
}
```

Lo importo en mi componente:

`import { ColorService } from '../services/color.service';`

En el constructor:

`private dataService: ColorService`

Y llamo la función ***LoadData()*** en mi componente:

`console.log(this.dataService.LoadData(this.colores));`

Esto me genera el siguiente error:
[image: error]

***Actualizacion 1:***

Al agregarlo al ***app.module*** como lo sugiere [**@jacknavarow**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/28035/jacknavarow), me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: error]

Comment: @JackNavaRow actualizado con tu sugerencia.

Comment: @JackNavaRow Lo coloque como dices y sigue persistiendo, adjunto una imagen para que veas como lo hice: [***main.module***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPwzb.png)

Comment: @JackNavaRow listo, agregandolo al ***app.component*** como dices, me soluciono el error. Gracias hermano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que importar tu servicio al Modulo de tu aplicacion , puede ser al principal o bien, exclusivo al modulo de donde estas trabajando:

```
@NgModule({ imports: [...] , providers: [ ..... , ColorService ], ... })
```